# R loop doesn't give an error but no output either, what could be the issue with the code?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I am new with R and got stuck with this loop code. I want to see in which rows column 3 values and column 2 values are unequal.

I have created a data frame list, by extracting columns from a dataset PFC_DATA.

list <- as.data.frame(PFC_Data[ ,c(1,6,10)])

And then created the loop with two conditions. Since the column 3 has a bunch of NAs, if it is an NA, then skip, otherwise, if column 3 has a value that is unequal to column 2 value, print the row numbers. That's the code:

```r
for (i in 1:1840) {
    if (list[[3]][[i]] == is.na())
      next
    else {
      if (list[[3]][[i]] != list[[2]][[i]]) {
        print(i)
      }
    }
}
```

I also tried =="NA". However, in either case nothing happens. I do not get any error, but no output either. Any ideas?

Comment: Will you be able to paste part of the data frame with relevant columns?

Comment: Unfortunately, but both columns 2 and 3 consist of the year and a quarter separated by a dot, the column 3 has some values NAs.

Comment: You're calling `is.na` on nothing. Without any data, I'm not sure what you'd actually be calling it on. Comparing a value to `"NA"` is only going to tell you whether that value is the same as the string "NA", not the special value of `NA` signifying a missing value